# Loading multiple files and saving them as variables

Tags: python, numpy, data-manipulation

I need to load data from different files and save it as arrays. I have multple files named `file.n.project.dat` where n is 1-100. So far, it seems that using numpy is the best way to start. Each file is a 5 by 5 array. I need to be able to add/multiply arrays later on in my code.

Right now I have this code to load the data but how do I make each file it's own variable?

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(1,101):
    np.loadtxt('file.' + str(i) + '.project.dat')
```

So what i need to do is load multiple files AND create a variable for each file.

I have seen previous posts using vars() to create the variables but I am unable to make that work for my problem.

Comment: Whenever you need multiple variables, you're most certainly looking for a `list`.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: `list`s are data containers: `p = [1,2,3,4,5]` - here one variable `p` holds 5 elements at once. The same thing can be done in your case.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. What do you want to do with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try appending each of the values to a list and then try to access the list elements as one by one to get values. 

`import numpy as np
l = []
for i in range(1,101):
    l.append(np.loadtxt('file.' + str(i) + '.project.dat'))
print l`

I believe your problem should be solved this way. l will have all the values that you want.

Comment: Thank you. I figured there was a better way to do it but couldn't quite figure it out. I need to switch my thinking to lists, I have mostly used small Matlab codes and variables work just fine with that.

Comment: Sure, working with lists avoid a lots of complications and allows the serial access. Good Luck

Comment: Python lists are more like MATLAB cells - places to collect diverse matrices and objects.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a new variable for each array you want to load from disk, store them all in a collection such as a list or dictionary.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np

# As a list
my_arrays = [np.loadtxt('file.{}.project.dat'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 101)]

# As a dictionary
my_arrays = {i: np.loadtxt('file.{}.project.dat'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 101)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary.

```
d = {}
for i in range(1, 101):
    d['matrix{}'.format(i)] = np.loadtxt('file.{}.project.dat'.format(i))
```

That does not create new varialbles, but could possibly solve your task, as you can refer to matrices by names, `d['matrix10']`

Comment: I hadn't heard of dictionaries yet. This is very helpful. I may try using this method. Thanks a lot